# how to remove a part of string within a string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a small app, when a checkbox is checked it's id value is added to a hidden field, when unchecked, it's id has to be removed from the hiddenfield value. I know how to add, but don't know how to remove. It's like say there is a string strValue="abcde"; how do I remove 'c' from the strValue using jQuery? Thank you.

Comment: A string within a string? Stringception??

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use **[replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**.

```
strValue.replace('c', '');
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/Yerjg/1/)**

I would suggest two things, looking at jQuerys [.Data() method for storing values](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), and at the very least making your list delimited by something such as a comma.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, make sure you take the result of replace method into a new string. It does not modify the original string.

```
var str = "somestring";

str = str.replace('some', 'someother');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know he string you're looking for...  The easy way.

```
strValue.replace('c','')
```

Or you can use a regular expression:

```
strValue.replace(regexp,newstring)
```

Comment: Id recommend removing the link to w3schools before you get downvoted by someone else :P. Check out mozilla developers network for references, and w3fools.com on why not to use w3schools